# Running Jest tests on a command line node script that writes to file

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have made a script to be run on the command line using node and two `process.argv` I run it like this:

`ts-node ./src/index.ts 'data.csv' 'brand'`

This works well and produces the expected results.

Without going in too much detail, this will read a csv file, in this case `data.csv` and then it looks for the header `brand` computes a few things and it outputs a csv file called `data_deduped.csv`

The scripts loolks like this:

```
export const Deduper = () => {
  const file = process.argv[2] 
  const header = process.argv[3]

  let json = []
  let counter = 0
  const unique = new Map()

  console.log(cyan('Working...'))

  const filePath = resolve(process.cwd(), file) 
  createReadStream(filePath)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('error', (error) => console.log(error))
    .on('data', (entry) => //... Do some work)
    .on('end', async () => //... write to file)
}

Deduper()
```

My question is, what is the better aproach to test this using Jest, should I read the output files or just mock up the csv inputs and outputs as arrays?